# Retrofit getting 400 bad request in local iis server but 200 in post man

Tags: android, iis, retrofit2, asp.net-core-2.0

I have local asp .net core 2 IIS server. I am getting result when I am using post request.

But I am getting error 400 when I am trying to request from andorid using retrofit2.

**My android device and server are connected to same wifi network**

postman returns

[image]

retrofit return 
[image]

**I am using my server pc ip instead of localhost for retrofit because retrofit does not support local host**

retrofit client

```
@POST("/Auth/authenticate")
Call<ApiResponse> createAccount(@Body Request user);
```

retrofit call

```
    request = new Request("01532383497", "123");

    retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getInstance();

    client = retrofit.create(APIClient.class);

    client.createAccount(request).enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
            String a=response.body().getType();
            Log.d("d","d");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("d","d");
        }
    });
```

Request object

```
public class Request {

String Username;
String Password;

public Request(String Username, String Password) {
    Username = Username;
    Password = Password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}
}
```

retrofit instance

```
public class RetrofitInstance {

public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static final String END_POINT = "http://192.168.0.104:50111/api/";

public static Retrofit getInstance(){
    if (retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(END_POINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }
    return retrofit;
}


}
```

Comment: remove / from Auth @POST("/Auth/authenticate")

Comment: @Pavya still not working

Comment: In postman you have added header check that also

Comment: @Pavya  it is postman  default header I did not add anything

Comment: You are trying with postman on your server??

Comment: Yes.It is in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand is that the Android emulator (a virtual device) has its own networking. So Google defines a magic IP address “10.0.2.2”. If you try to browse to this IP address, the requests would be routed to “127.0.0.1” loopback adapter of the host machine. However, this magic won’t work for IIS Express by default.

1. First, replace your 192.168.0.104 address to 10.0.2.2 in **END_POINT**.

   ```
   public static final String END_POINT = "http://10.0.2.2:50111/api/";
   ```
2. Download [Jexus Manager](https://www.jexusmanager.com/) and install.
3. Click here and set up the IIS(Check with your VS version) - [Managing IIS Express Servers](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#managing-iis-express-servers).
4. Go to Edit site -> bindings

[image: Jexux manager]

5. Add new binding with correct values and the Hostname should be 127.0.0.1.

   - In my case, my access point from the local -  `https://localhost:44317/api`
   - after the add new binding, it shows as, 
     [image: Jxux manager binding]
   - These are my settings. please change with your settings.
6. Run the server.

It seems that the Android magic sets Host header to “127.0.0.1” so that IIS Express can process the requests in this way.

**For further information -** [How to Let Android Emulator Access IIS Express](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your request is wrong please try below way.

```
@POST("Auth/authenticate")
Call<ApiResponse> createAccount(@Field("Username") String username, @Field("Password") String password);
```

Comment: Please check your API with this URL public static final String END_POINT = "http://192.168.0.104:50111/api/"; in postman let us know whether it is working or not.

Comment: getting Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Comment: Please use local host URL which one are you using in postman.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request is wrong, Try below code,

retrofit client

```
@POST("Auth/authenticate")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ApiResponse> createAccount(@FieldMap Map<String,String> params);
```

retrofit call

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Username", "01532383497");
    params.put("Password", "123");

retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getInstance();

client = retrofit.create(APIClient.class);

client.createAccount(params).enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
        String a=response.body().getType();
        Log.d("d","d");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("d","d");
    }
  });
```

Comment: stil getting 400

Comment: I got your issue. In your postman I can see "api" but in your retrofit url there is no "api" keyword. So can you change your END_POINT = "http://192.168.0.104:50111/" and @POST("Auth/authenticate") with @POST("api/Auth/authenticate").

Comment: @AndroidTeam that isn't an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using local server in postman like **localhost**.

It means you have to run your project in Emulator with your pc. and your pc and local server pc both should be in same network.

And if you are test with your device then your local server machine network and your wifi network of your testing device should be in same network.

Comment: @Amir Hossain : it's fixed.